# Microsoft Purview connection lost after ADF deployment through DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, parameter-passing, azure-purview

We have an Azure Data Factory connected to a github repository, which we deploy to the production environment through a DevOps Pipeline upon accepted pull requests to a certain branch. Now the production environment is connected to Microsoft Purview, but this connection is lost after every deployment through the DevOps Pipeline.

I have tried to add the Microsoft Purview properties to the deployment parameters in the github repository. I used [this microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connect-data-factory-to-azure-purview#connect-to-microsoft-purview-account-in-data-factory) as inspiration and I looked at the JSON of the data factory with the Purview connection in place to determine the path to the parameter. Which would then be $.properties.purviewConfiguration.purviewResourceId (see image below)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sASQX.png)

Adding this property to the parameters will successfully deploy the ADF, but the Purview connection is not created. Neither is the property visible in the JSON view of the data factory and if there was an existing connection with Purview, this is now lost.

The following is how I added the property to the parameters.json:

```
{
    "df-my-adf-instance": [
        {
            "name": "$.properties.purviewConfiguration.purviewResourceId",
            "value": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/rg-my-purview-resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Purview/accounts/prvw-my-purview-resource",
            "action": "update"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using ARM template to deploy to ADF?  How you deploy the resource in Azure DevOps?